# About application settings

Tags: c#, .net

So i have few questions about .net application settings. I have added an application settings and i can add and remove settings but my question is is there a way to add a table of settings. For example i have in the settings file :

```
 NumberOfPrinetrs  int          4
 SomethingElse     string       dsffds
```

Is there a way to add

```
Printer1
    location string xxxxx
    number   int    xxxxx

Printer2
    location string xxxxx
    number   int    xxxxx
```

and another question is it possible to add additional settings at runtime and if it is possible how?

Thanks for all the help in advance and Merry Christmas to all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could separate your values with a ',' and ';' and then parse them when reading.

In such a way you can still access them like your normal `NumberOfPrinters` and `SomethingElse` values.

I would create a wrapper class that handles this for you and that you can use every time you need some printer information.

```
<key="Printers" value="Printer1,location,number;Printer2,location,number"/>
```

Your wrapper class would then expose a list(or dictionary) of Printer objects with the properties Name, Location and Number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use every class .Net Framework has to offer as settings type. I think things from here [System.Collections.Specialized Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.aspx) can help you. In your case you can use for example NameValueCollection class.